# How convert xaml to code behind?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, code-behind

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Block" Foreground="White" FontSize="13">
    <SLMultiBinding:BindingUtil.MultiBinding>
        <SLMultiBinding:MultiBinding TargetProperty="Text" Converter="{StaticResource ConverterConcat}">
            <Binding Path="name"/>    
            <Binding Path="name"/>                          
        </SLMultiBinding:MultiBinding>
    </SLMultiBinding:BindingUtil.MultiBinding>
</TextBlock>
```

I could only translate

```
var binding = new MultiBinding()
{
    TargetProperty = "Text",
    Converter = new Restaurant.Helpers.Converter.ConcatConverter(),
    Bindings = new ObservableCollection<Binding>()
    {
        new Binding("name"), 
        new Binding("name")
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for how to set [Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

In your case it will be something like `BindingUtil.SetMultiBinding(Block, binding);`